# how to print a list-column of ggplots to pdf?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, purrr

Consider this `funny` example

```
mydata <- data_frame(group = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
           x = c(1,2,3,5,6,7),
           y = c(3,5,6,4,3,2))

> mydata
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  group     x     y
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         1     3
2 a         2     5
3 a         3     6
4 b         5     4
5 b         6     3
6 b         7     2
```

Here I can `nest()` by group, and store a group-based `ggplot` into a `list-column`. Crazy stuff.

```
> mydata %>% group_by(group) %>% 
+   nest() %>% 
+   mutate(myplot = map(data, ~ggplot(data = .x, aes(x = x, y = x)) + geom_point()))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  group data             myplot  
  <chr> <list>           <list>  
1 a     <tibble [3 x 2]> <S3: gg>
2 b     <tibble [3 x 2]> <S3: gg>
```

However, I would like to use `map` to print each of these charts into a single `pdf`. That is, one `pdf` page per group.

Here I am at a loss. How can I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you expand on why you need to use `map()`/`walk()` for this?  Are you trying to avoid the intermediate step of storing the plots? If I want to save all the plots in a list into a single pdf I usually use `pdf()`, where the work-flow is to initialize the file with `pdf()`, pass the list (like `mydata$myplots`), then `dev.off()`.  I have an example [here](https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/08/20/automating-exploratory-plots/#saving-all-plots-to-one-pdf)

Comment: @aosmith You still need the print call unless you're in interactive mode right ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Yes, you need to explicitly `print()` when not using `pdf()` interactively, like using `pdf()` inside a function.  [Here's one example](https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/08/20/automating-exploratory-plots/#saving-groups-of-plots-together).

Comment: hi your link is very cool! essentially this is part of a program that spills the pdf of ggplots at some point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just open the pdf device and print them :)

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata <- data_frame(group = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
                     x = c(1,2,3,5,6,7),
                     y = c(3,5,6,4,3,2))

mydata2 <- mydata %>% group_by(group) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(myplot = map(data, ~ggplot(data = .x, aes(x = x, y = x)) + geom_point()))

pdf()
print(mydata2$myplot)
dev.off()
```

As @aosmith comments you can skip the print call if you're using R interactively, but be careful that if you wrap it later into a function it won't work anymore, so I'd recommend to keep it explicit.

If you want to chain it :

```
pdf()
mydata %>% group_by(group) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(myplot = map(data, ~ggplot(data = .x, aes(x = x, y = x)) + geom_point())) %>%
  pull(myplot) %>%
  print
dev.off()
```

The first argument of `pdf` is the path of your printed file and by default it's `"Rplots.pdf"`, so it will be in your working folder. See `?pdf` for more.

Comment: I actually dont see the output pdf when I do so in Rstudio. Is it supposed to pop out?

Comment: See the end of my answer, let me know if it helps

Comment: thanks, i was also wondering how I can control the heigth/weight of the charts produced, but I think this is worth a new question. I will create it soon

Comment: for this see the last sentence of my answer ;), width and height are the 2nd and 3rd parameters

Comment: thanks! but I am now using `grid.arrange`, which complicates the matter a bit. do you mind looking at it? :) thanks again! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52275228/how-to-change-the-height-weight-in-a-ggplot-printed-to-pdf