# how to change the height/weight in a ggplot printed to pdf?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider this `list` of `ggplots`:

```
mydata <- data_frame(group = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
                     x = c(1,2,3,5,6,7),
                     y = c(3,5,6,4,3,2)) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(myplot = map(data, ~ggplot(data = .x, aes(x = x, y = x)) + geom_point()))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  group data             myplot  
  <chr> <list>           <list>  
1 a     <tibble [3 x 2]> <S3: gg>
2 b     <tibble [3 x 2]> <S3: gg>
```

I can print the plots contained in `myplot` using the simple:

```
pdf('P://mychart.pdf')
do.call("grid.arrange", c(mydata $myplot))
dev.off()
```

However, the charts are all contained in a square, wasting a lot of space on the margin. How can I get control over the margins here so that the charts are all wider?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `ggsave()` instead of the `pdf()` route. `ggsave()` allows `width` and `height` parameters.

Comment: ok thanks, but how can I do that using my initial list of ggplots?

Comment: I guess this is platform specific. I get no margins huge margins on Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ggsave`:

```
ggsave("P://mychart.pdf", do.call("arrangeGrob", mydata$myplot), 
  width = 9, height = 6, units = "in")
```

[image]

The plot as seen above is a `.png`, but `ggsave` works perfectly with `.pdf`.

---

If you instead want to plot every item in the `myplot` list as single `.pdf` files, you could use `mapply`:

```
mapply(function(x, y){
  ggsave(paste0("P://mychart", x, ".pdf"), y, width = 9, height = 6, units = "in")
},1:length(mydata$myplot), mydata$myplot)
```

This will produce to plots, `mychart1.pdf` and `mychart2.pdf`.

Comment: very nice. I wonder how I can tweak this code to have `ggsave` print each `ggplot on a different pdf page. any ideas?

Comment: You mean without using `gridExtra`? I'll add an example using `mapply`.