# How to add geoms to a list-column of ggplot`s

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

Building on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52265591/how-to-print-a-list-column-of-ggplots-to-pdf) question, I would to add geoms to the received plot by row, after I unnested the data.frame, in order to get a plot for each row, with the row data highlighted within its group.

```
library(tidyverse) # using  version 1.3.0
mydata <- data_frame(group = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
                     x = c(1,2,3,5,6,7),
                     y = c(3,5,6,4,3,2))
mydata2 <- mydata %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(myplot = map(data, ~ggplot(data = .x, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()))
mydata2
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   group [2]
  group data             myplot
  <chr> <list>           <list>
1 a     <tibble [3 x 2]> <gg>  
2 b     <tibble [3 x 2]> <gg>
```

The desired output for the first row is this:

```
mydata2$myplot[[1]] + geom_point(mapping = aes(x=1,y=3),color = "red")
```

[image]

---

However, when trying to implement this on the unnested data.frame, I fail.
Here are my three attempts, and their outputs:

```
mydata3 <- mydata2 %>% 
  unnest(data) %>% 
  mutate(myplot2 = myplot + geom_point(mapping = aes(x=x,y=y),color = "red"))
mydata3$myplot2[[1]]
NULL
Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: `myplot2`. 


mydata4 <- mydata2 %>% 
  unnest(data) %>% 
  mutate(myplot2 = list(myplot[[1]] + geom_point(mapping = aes(x=x,y=y),color = "red")))
mydata4$myplot2[[1]]
```

[image]

All points became red!
I got the same output for this attempt:

```
mydata5 <- mydata2 %>% 
  unnest(data) %>% 
  mutate(myplot2 = map(myplot,~.x + geom_point(mapping = aes(x=x,y=y),color = "red")))
mydata5$myplot2[[1]]
```

So my question is, is there a way to get the first plot using the tidyverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. The trick is to use `pmap` to loop "rowise" over `x`, `y` and `myplot`. The `x` and `y` coordinates are passed to `geom_point` via the data argument, which is simply a df with only one row:

```r
library(tidyverse)
mydata <- data_frame(group = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
                     x = c(1,2,3,5,6,7),
                     y = c(3,5,6,4,3,2))

mydata2 <- mydata %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(myplot = map(data, ~ggplot(data = .x, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()))

mydata3 <- mydata2 %>%
  unnest(data) %>% 
  mutate(myplot2 = pmap(list(x, y, myplot), ~ ..3 + geom_point(data = data.frame(x = ..1, y = ..2), mapping = aes(x, y), color = "red")))

mydata3$myplot2[[1]]
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>